# How to snap the center of a face to another face?

Tags: modeling, transforms, snapping

I have a sword handle and I want it centered below a completely differently object that has a face on the bottom with a vertex in the middle. I could also snap a central vertex to the other one but I don't know how. How can i do this?

Answer (score 10):

You can use **Vertex Snapping**.

[image]

You can enable it by clicking on the magnet icon or If you wan't to use it temporarily, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

I would recommend setting the second option to active:

[image]

You use it by moving your object in edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: How? I need these to come together @GiantCowFilms

Comment: I rephrase: The center of the one i move meets at the vertex when doing it in object mode, how could i translate the whole thing in edit mode?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a helper object as the target location agent:

1. Select the target face you want to snap to, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> -> *Hook to New Object*, which will create a new empty object at the face center;
2. select the target part and keep the target face active, be sure to use **Acive Element** as Pivot point;
3. Turn on Snap tool, set *Target Element* to **Vertex**, and *Snap Target* to **Active**.
4. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the selected part towards empty, <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it was successfully snapped as expected.
5. Switch to **Object** mode, delete the empty, as well as the new created **Hook** modifier.

As shown in the GIF below:

[image]

**Tip:**

- When creating the agent object, you can also do it by first <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>to snap 3D Cursor to the face, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Empty. No Hook modifier will be created that way.
- When snapping, you may want to turn off the **Limit Selection to Visible** button (as I did in the GIF), or simply press <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to **Wireframe** display mode. in order to see through it.