# Join duplicated side back on to side duplicated from

Tags: modeling

I have a bag and a side of the bag that I duplicated - they look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to connect the duplicated side back onto the side that I duplicated because the other side of the bag has two faces whereas this side only has the one and .

I've looked [around](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33843/how-to-merge-two-objects-in-blender) and it seems to be that to connect two objects you have to select a side to delete from each before you can connect them. All I want to do is to add this side back on and connect it to the same vertices it was duplicated from.

Comment: "connect the duplicated side back onto the side that I duplicated" - ? Are you sure there isn't any recursion involved? As I've got it you want duplicated face to attach to the adjacent face of the mesh? I don't really think there's a sense in doing that, you can just recreate a face in place. If you really want to attach it you can use snapping, e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20891/how-to-snap-the-center-of-a-face-to-another-face

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you describe you are basically "doing nothing". You duplicate a face and then proceed to merge it back into the one it came from again virtually eliminating it. What have you gained from that, other than lots of extra steps? To be clear if you join them back the duplicated face will disappear leaving you exactly where you were before.

Comment: Well if that happened then I'm quite confused as to what to do. I'll need to run through some Blender tutorials then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mr Zak - it worked.

In my particular version of Blender (2.77) I first had to select the side - select the Magnet symbol, select the Cube symbol right beside it to select the "Snap Element" (Volume, Face, Edge, Vertex or Increment) and then position it they way it needed it.

[image]