# Can't identify where this lip is in hiding in this model

Tags: modeling

This is somewhat related to my previous question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80212/join-duplicated-side-back-on-to-side-duplicated-from/80218#80218), however this question is related to the partial invisibility of one of the sides when exported and loaded into ThreeJS.

In there it looks like this:[image]

Notice the pink lip at the top of this side. In Blender I've extended the red side to the top of the bag so it should cover whatever this pink lip is - the problem is I don't know where it's coming from.

Based on the "Edit Mode" view there are only two sides here, both are the same height and width & both are facing the same direction (outside). I've also recalculated the normals after I flipped the directions but I still see this pink lip. Why?

Here's the Blender view with the two sides hidden:

[image]

Any advice on this would be good.

P.S. It has also been suggested that this can be caused by not using a THREE.DoubleSide but I am using that as the material so this shouldn't be the issue:[image: base bag with no colours added]

**EDIT** 
Link to the uploaded bag:

[image]

Comment: so this happens only in threejs? if so, maybe ask on their support, as it could be something unsupported, or an error... or, upload the model here (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we could check the mesh for hidden issues?

Comment: I've uploaded the blender to the site you mentioned above. See my edit for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not (yet) an answer, but at least I can show something that seems weird in your model:

[image]

[image]

You have some different faces for interior and exterior sides of your bag, but their normals are all directed outwards, instead of being as usual, ie: I expected the exterior face normal pointing outside, and the interior face normal pointing inside the bag.

It seems there are many face normals set like this, it seems a bit weird imho.

I will try to learn Threejs basic concepts to experiment (never used before, but interesting) but I would try before making this mesh look better in Blender before...

edit: imho, this mesh has many problems (many of them clearly found by the 3d print addon mesh checker, or the mesh analysis tool, btw) which can confuse an external engine: face distortion (non planar) face overlaps, and others...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I've played around with the face direction of the faces both inside and outside the model and have had different results in ThreeJS. E.g. when flipped in sometimes the face becomes invisible, though sometimes this is caused by ThreeJS itself. Thanks for examining this.

Comment: Your on the right track. Those extra faces are duplicates all the way around the bag. move them out and find a second extrusion matching the red sides. The two small sides also have duplicates but they are closer together so don't stand out as much.

Comment: @Katana24 how do you load the model in Threejs? obj format exported from blender? We could try to load the exact model you load in the online editor perhaps (I mean https://threejs.org/editor/)? Or, describe how to reproduce exactly so it could be easier to sort it out, as the effect is perhaps not so strictly blender related...

Comment: Ok so you have already loaded it in. Is that the same bag that I supplied or did you modify it slightly?

Comment: No, sorry, please describe how exactly you export that -blend file as .obj (export options, parameters), so I can replicate exactly.

Comment: Hi m.ardito - I awarded you the bounty as your images above helped me to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But if you feel like explaining a bit on how you solved, it will help future readers too. Even better if you wish to answer your own question putting all details, in particular if it was solved in blender modeling: that would be very useful, and I won't mind about losing those rep points...