# Easy way of snapping Objects and Faces to vertices?

Tags: snapping

I`m trying to migrate to blender (2.8) but can't figure out how to simply snap a face or faces or objects or edges etc based on vertices (see example below of how it is done in 3dsmax) as the gizmo concept seems to work differently in blender. What is the best workflow to achieve this behavior in blender? thanks in advance!

[image: 3dsmax example of hovering over vertex and dragging to vertex snap]

[image: Blender drag behavior]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20891/how-to-snap-the-center-of-a-face-to-another-face/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42710/translate-like-sketchup-move/

Comment: Blender snapping system is crude and missing some basic features. Also look into https://blenderartists.org/t/np-station/686462

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable "Snapping".

[image]

Switch to the edit mode.

[image]

Enable snapping by selecting clicking the magnet icon. Select what you want to snap to.

[image]

Grab the mesh and let it snap into position.

Comment: While this works it doesn't really address the issue of specifying a particular snap target

Comment: thanks for the feedback and suggestions! When I grab the center ring in the gizmo and move toward vertices the selected element just seems to decide for itself which vertex to use with no way for me to influence that? it seems to be.... aproach vector based? this seems weird

Comment: I just tested with blender 2.79 keymap and there you can grab with g while near a vertex which helps. Has the grab feature moved in the industry standard keymapping? can't find anything called grab in the keymap

Comment: @akaChris Yes can't select it directly, you just move the cursor roughly where you want it to snap. I'm not aware of another approach that would allow this. G is still grab in the default keymap, not sure if the industry standard keymapping changed something there.

Comment: ok so it`s unmapped in the industry standard keymap (3dView > Move). So grab is a bit better but only seems to snap to border vertices, not to vertices within a surface

Comment: @akaChris *"seems to snap to border vertices, not to vertices within a surface"* it will if you choose snapping target as Active and select vertex inside of the surface last (make it active). This however works in Edit mode